# The security ID structure is invalid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I i'm trying to install crm on a server, but getting this error..
System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantAspNetServiceAccountAccessAction failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The security ID structure is invalid.
any help ?

have trying:
reinstall my server
closing the server with my sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem have been found and solved.

The problem lies in the administrator being member of many AD groups.

The solution:

1. Open regedit
2. Browse to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters"
3. Create new DWORD named MaxTokenSize
4. Set value data to 65535 (Decimal)
5. Close regedit and reboot server

Cause:

The user cannot authenticate because the Kerberos token that is generated during authentication attempts has a fixed maximum size. Transports such as remote procedure call (RPC) and HTTP rely on the MaxTokenSize value when they allocate buffers for authentication. In Windows 2000 (the original release version), the MaxTokenSize value is 8,000 bytes. In Windows 2000 Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2003, the MaxTokenSize value is 12,000 bytes.

Kerberos uses the Privilege Attribute Certificate (PAC) field of the Kerberos packet to transport Active Directory Group membership. Starting with Windows Server 2012, this also applies to the Active Directory Claims information (Dynamic Access Control) field. If there are many group memberships for the user, and if there are many claims for the user or the device that is being used, these fields can occupy lots of space in the packet.

If a user is a member of more than 120 groups, the buffer that is determined by the MaxTokenSize value is not large enough. Therefore, users cannot authenticate, and they may receive an "out of memory" error message. Before you apply the hotfix that is described in this article, every group that is added to a user account increases this buffer by 40 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to install this on a server logged in as a user that doesn't have the required permissions. Taken from [MS Dynamics on Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3176.how-to-install-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx):

Required for installation of Dynamics CRM 2011

- Domain administrator

If you cannot be domain administrator the following privileges are required:

- Member of Active Directory Domain Users
- Permissions to create security groups in Active Directory (alernatively you can ask an  administrator to pre-create the required security groups; you must then install Microsoft  Dynamics CRM 2011 from the command line specifying a configuration file).
- Member of the Administrators group on the computer where you install the CRM
- Read and write permissions on the folder 'Program Files' on that computer
- Member of the Administrators group on the computer where SQL Server installed
- SQL Server sysadmin.
- Reporting Services:

  - Content Manager root level
  - System administrator for site-wide SSRS

**Tip:**

To find out what security groups the logged in user belongs to open up a command prompt and run the following command:

```
gpresult /V
```

Comment: When you say you use admin user, do you mean Domain Administrator? It's very important that it is a Domain Admin (or at least has the above rights) because you need rights to change the Active Directory and other such things. Other admins (such as local administrators) will not necessarily have these rights.

Comment: It's domain administrator i'm using

Comment: "Built-in account for administering the computer/domain"

Comment: That is usually the description you will see on a Local Administrator on your machine so that doesn't necessarily mean it's a "Domain Administrator". To get a clear picture open up a command prompt and run the following: `gpresult /V`  Then Check the part that says "The user is a part of the following security groups". If that list contains "Domain Admins" then yes, you are indeed using a domain administrator. What I expect is the only administrator group you will see is "BUILTIN\Administrators", which will usually not have adequate rights to install CRM.

Comment: I get this info when i run it:
INFO: The user "xxxx\administrator" does not have RSOP data.

Comment: Check your event logs for a better error. I'm guessing it will give you more info than this message